# Inmo Air Smart glasses. Resize screen

Tags: android, adb

I bought a pair of these a few months ago, but they didn't come with prescription lenses. So last week, I had a technician make lenses for them.

Now, the problem seems to be that the bottom of the (projected) screen is out of my range of vision. I have to rest the glasses on the bridge of my nose to see the entire screen.

Anyone know an `adb` command to solve this?

Comment: Don't think that's within the realm of concern of `adb`, but I'm not sure. To be completely honest, while Android is indeed based on a Linux kernel, its userland is anything but POSIX/UNIX, and you might hence not find the best experts on it here. There's an android sister site, [Android Stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/), which might work out better for you.